# After updating Google Ads SDK addTestDevice is deprecated, How to resolve?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, google-ads-api

After updating **`Google Ads SDK to 19.0.0`** gives a deprecated warning message for **`addTestDevice()`**, while I searched [this link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes) for resolving the issue but not succeed.
how can I resolve it?

**Here my code**

```java
mAdView.loadAd(new RequestConfiguration.Builder
       .setTestDeviceIds(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) // show error
       .setTestDeviceIds(DEV_ID) // show error
       .build());
```

and developer site suggestion

> Deprecated AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice(). Use
> RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds() instead.

Answer (score 82):

I did like this:

```
List<String> testDevices = new ArrayList<>();
testDevices.add(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration
    = new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setTestDeviceIds(testDevices)
        .build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

AdView adView = new AdView(context);
// ... invoke some methods of adView ...
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

[The official reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/RequestConfiguration) says that a `RequestConfiguration` is the global configuration that will be used for every `AdRequest`. In my understanding, once you have `setRequestConfiguration()`, your `AdRequest`s individually don't need to set test devices anymore.

Comment: is RequestConfiguration  is required in every Activity?

Comment: @Attaullah Yes, I think so. Because AdView's argument is Activity's Context. But I have no idea about the word 'Global' explicitly means either an Activity-wide or an Application-wide.

Comment: If I true understand the RequestConfiguration is required once in the first Activity.

Comment: Notice that according the Developers Page: "Android emulators are automatically configured as test devices.""

Comment: I used this configuration at MainActivity and all ads in different activties now have a black "Test Ad" box. So this configuration can be set only once.

Comment: I do not if another way would with the ConsentInformation object like   
ConsentInformation.getInstance(applicationContext).addTestDevice("XXX") ?

Answer (score 5):

If you use Android Emulators there is no need to `setTestDeviceIds()` method because emulators are automatically configured as test devices .

But if you use a real devices or other emulators as a test device you must use it

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231");
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

To get the Device ID Check the logcat output for a message that looks like the one below, which shows you your device ID and how to add it as a test device:

```
I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231"))
to get test ads on this device."
```

[Source :](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this in my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` function:

```
val testDeviceIds = listOf("MY DEVICE ID")
val config = RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build()
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(config)
MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

Comment: Do you know if ConsentInformation.getInstance(applicationContext).addTestDevice("xxx") do the same?

Comment: Is it possible to add the current device and that's it? Without putting a fixed string of it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  String testDeviceId = "xxx";

final RequestConfiguration.Builder requestConfigurationBuilder = new RequestConfiguration.Builder(); 

requestConfigurationBuilder.setTestDeviceIds(Collections.singletonList(testDeviceId)).build();

final RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = requestConfigurationBuilder.build();

MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```