# getting error on adding test device for google admob in android studio

Tags: android-studio, admob

I am not able to write the line ".addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)" after AdRequest.Builder().
It's is not giving any options for .addTestDevice.

My Code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I want it like below code but android studio is not giving me the option:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because the `addTestDevice` is **deprecated**.

Try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60539407/13558801).

[Official doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads).

Hope you helpful!